# Different Aliases produce different Result for exactly same Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Below two versions of the same exactly query

> Version 1 (uses k as alias in inner SELECT):

```
SELECT k, w_vol, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY k DESC) AS rank1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY w_vol DESC) AS rank2
FROM (
  SELECT w_vol, c_date AS k FROM 
    (SELECT 1590 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1599 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1602 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1609 AS c_date, 2 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1610 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
)
ORDER BY 1
```

> Version 2 (uses l as alias in inner SELECT):

```
SELECT l, w_vol, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l DESC) AS rank1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY w_vol DESC) AS rank2
FROM (
  SELECT w_vol, c_date AS l FROM 
    (SELECT 1590 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1599 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1602 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1609 AS c_date, 2 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1610 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
)
ORDER BY 1
```

Below is output i am consistently getting for both queries (note `No Cached Results` is used)

[image]

I don't have problem with understanding why this or that result is generated (it is relatively trivial) - BUT - I expected result be the same no matter what alias is used - it is just alias at all!

> **Question**: Why I am consistently getting one result for Version 1 and another for Version 2?

**Note**: I am not interested in recommendations on how to re-write query differently to "hide" the problem! Please do not bother with answers in this direction!

```
Forgot to mention:
```

Most of aliases produce same result as with 'l', but very few as with'k'. Another example of such is 'x'. Just wanted to make it clear  - it is not just one particular alias that is problematic. And even more - problematic alias depends on name of fileds.

*So i think it is some hashing issue that involves fields/aliases names - but this is just my wild guess!*

Comment: Of course, the real issue (if it is) is much broader! I just isolated it and scaled down to extremely simplistic example to make it easy to comprehend

Comment: Why do you consider this "problematic"? As mentioned in the answer below, both responses are valid and correct. Where the ordering is underspecified, the query engine is free to pick any ordering for any reason.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a specific explanation for the behavior, but note that **both results are still correct**: the only difference between the results is that a different order was chosen when sorting several rows that have the same value (`1`) for the column being sorted (`w_vol`).

Generally speaking, BigQuery does not promise any particular ordering when applying `ORDER BY` to equal values, and that ordering may vary across different executions of the same query for any reason.

I agree it's interesting that the ordering seems to depend on the alias, but I could see plenty of plausible explanations for why this happens--for example, the engine might iterate through a list of fields that use analytic functions, and changing the alias might change the order in which those analytic functions are evaluated, which in turn changes the ordering of rows with equal values when sorting by one column.

Comment: It seems this answer is being downvoted due to being "undesirable", although it is correct. This is an abuse of the voting system. If a particular defined behaviour would be preferred, and it's currently undefined, users should consider making a Feature Request in the [BigQuery Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list).

Comment: @Nick you are not correct! the answer is totally incorrect in terms of specific question and does not answer the question at all! I recommend reading question again! few times!

Comment: I think you actually need to re-read your own question and Jeremy's answer... I don't know how you can believe that it *doesn't* answer your question. The behaviour is undefined, and you've noticed a reproducible side-effect of what is likely some internal hashing based on alias names.

Comment: i truly believe  - you are wrong! if behavior is undefined  - why it is so consistently undefined!? anyway  - if you still cannot see the point - i don't think you will be able to - so i am out of this convo :o)

Comment: When behaviour is not defined in documentation, regardless of its apparent, potentially-transient consistency, it is still undefined behaviour and should not be coded against if you don't enjoy suddenly having to change your code since you relied on undefined behaviour which suddenly became defined differently to how it was before. This wisdom should be understood by every developer when it comes to coding against documentation. Software documentation and the very concept of "defined behaviour" exist so that reasonable expectations can be coded-against. Is there anything unclear still?