# Same exactly Query Fails or "Succeeds" with different Aliases used

Tags: google-bigquery

Below two versions of the same exactly query

> Version 1 (uses k as alias in inner SELECT):

```
SELECT k as [year], w_vol, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY k DESC) AS rank1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY w_vol DESC) AS rank2
FROM (
  SELECT w_vol, c_date AS k FROM 
    (SELECT 1590 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1599 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1602 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1609 AS c_date, 2 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1610 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
)
ORDER BY 1
```

> Version 2 (uses l as alias in inner SELECT):

```
SELECT l as [year], w_vol, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l DESC) AS rank1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY w_vol DESC) AS rank2
FROM (
  SELECT w_vol, c_date AS l FROM 
    (SELECT 1590 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1599 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1602 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1609 AS c_date, 2 AS w_vol),
    (SELECT 1610 AS c_date, 1 AS w_vol),
)
ORDER BY 1
```

Below is output i am consistently getting for both queries (note `No Cached Results` is used)

[image]

I expected result be the same no matter what alias is used - it is just alias at all!

> **Question**: Why I am consistently getting failure for Version 1 and "success" for Version 2?

Comment: This is strangest bug in BigQuery that I have seen in a while. Will look into it in more detail and give update tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you Mosha! I spent whole last night to isolate the issue and present it in reprodusable manner - this one , as well as another one  - http://stackoverflow.com/q/36781049/5221944

Comment: Kudos for finding this! My impression is that the error only happens with the alias `k` and only with two different partition windows. (I can reproduce the error when I substitute `count(*)` for `row_number()` but not when I align the `order by` clauses.)

Comment: 'k' is not the only alias when this happens. and this also depends on names of real fields – for now just try 'x' as alias to test my statement

Comment: I would really love to know what is special about `k` and `x` that triggers the error.

Comment: If everything goes well, Wednesday morning I will be able to give you solution.

Comment: Updated SQL dialect seems not have this issue - at least I am not reproducing it as simple as it was for legacy one. But without explanations from Google - how we can know that it is actually fixed in new dialect and secondly - it is just alpha so we are still anchored to legacy dialect for quite a while - would be great to understand what it is and hopefully not to get cliché about nature of ‘order by’ that is known by any/most newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an instance of the bug I filed as [issue 403](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=403&can=1&q=partition). The error seems to occur when combining aliases with partition windows of different scope. The team member that responded suggests this will be fixed in the upcoming overhaul of their sql dialect.

That said, what is new to me is that this error only occurs with certain aliases. I haven't been able to reproduce your error with any alias other than `k`. It would be great if someone from the BigQuery team could confirm whether this is indeed the same issue and whether it will be fixed with the promised update.

Comment: 'k' is not the only alias when this happens. and this also depends on names of real fields –  
 for now just try 'x' as alias to test my statement

Comment: Yes, this is fixed in the new dialect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather interesting bug, but the good news are that it is fixed in BigQuery's standard SQL. For details how to try it out - check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Comment: i see - no real answer :o(. anyway, thank you Mosha. Can you at least check if same "interesting bug" can explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781049/different-aliases-produce-different-result-for-exactly-same-query

Comment: Well, the answer is that it's a bug. That's the "why". As with your other question, this doesn't make the answer wrong. In fact, it's the only real answer. The issue is that the actual behavior isn't inline with the expected or desired behavior, and the place to enact change is [BigQuery issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list).